# ForEach esperar pelo resultado select para então prosseguir

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tenho um `forEach` que percorre uma lista de códigos e dentro dele tenho um select que consulta os registros do banco de dados. Após o `forEach`, os dados são mandados do meu servidor até o meu cliente, mas o `forEach` não espera o resultado do `SELECT` chegar para executar o próximo elemento.

Como posso fazer para o `forEach` esperar o resultado

```
lista.forEach(function (row) {
   db.query("select * from cad_prospectos where = ?", [row.codigo], function(err, pesquisa){
     result.push(pesquisa)
   })
})
cb(result)
```

minha função de retorno `cb` retorna vazio

Comment: Colocar o código que você tem atualmente vai ajudar a responder a pergunta...

Comment: Coloquei o código espero que consiga entender.

Comment: Saberia dizer se `db.query` retorna um *Promise*? Aliás, ele é nativo do NodeJS ou é de algum pacote?

Comment: Ele é do pacote do Firebird  `Firebird.attach(firebirdConfig, function (err, db)`

Comment: Se o query devolve um `Promisse` pode guardar todos num array e utilizar [`Promisse.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547292/use-promise-to-process-mysql-return-value-in-node-js] consegui achar um jeito bom de fazer aqui, minha query não devolve uma Promisse, então fiz algumas modificações seguindo o exemplo desse link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar Promise e Promise.all para fazer isso. A biblioteca async é excelente mas fazia mais sentido antes de as Promises terem sido integradas na linguagem.

Assim o teu código poderia ser:

```js
function selectAsync(cod) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    db.query("select * from cad_prospectos where = ?", [cod], (err, data) => {
      if (err) rej(err);
      else res(data);
    });
  });
}

const selects = lista.map(row => selectAsync(row.codigo));
Promise.all(selects).then(cb).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Pois é, assim funcionou bem so fiz algumas alterações para retornar pro meu cliente, não ficou como eu pensava que iria ficar mas esta funcionando perfeitamente e é isto que importa, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Trabalhe com Promessas:

```
function consulta(lista) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var pesquisas = [];
    var queue = 0; // tamanho da fila a processar
    lista.forEach(function (row) {
       queue++; // adiciona uma pesquisa na fila
       db.query("select * from cad_prospectos where = ?", [row.codigo], function(err, pesquisa){
         pesquisas.push(pesquisa);
         queue--; // pesquisa terminada, sai da fila
         if(queue === 0) { 
            // quando a fila zerar, retorna todas as pesquisas
            defer.resolve(pesquisas); 
         }
       });
    });
    // retorna uma promessa de pesquisas;
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Para consumir isso:

```
consulta()
  .then(function (pesquisas) { 
    console.log('pesquisas', pesquisas); 
   });
```

Para saber mais:
https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o `db.query` não retorne uma `Promise`, mas você pode criar uma promise para que ela retorne quando houver um resultado para sua consulta, algo parecido com o código abaixo;

```js
// Função a ser executada para cada elemento da lista
var fn = function asyncQuery(row) {
  // Retorna uma promise que será finalizada quando o db.query for executado
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    db.query("select * from cad_prospectos where = ?", [row.codigo], function(err, pesquisa) {
      resolve(pesquisa)
    })
  });
};

// Executa a função fn para cada elemento da lista
var promises = lista.map(fn)

// Aguarda a finalização de todas as promises e obtem seu resultado
Promise.all(promises).then(result => cb(result))
```

Comment: Sim isso me ajudou bastante já estou quase conseguindo, estou pesquisando na biblioteca do "async" se existe alguma função que pode me ajudar também.