# Sincronização de dados, mysql e promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async, promises

Sou iniciante em Node.js e estou tentando entender por que não consigo trazer o resultado esperado da minha API.

Tenho uma aplicação que envia para uma API em Node um array com dados a serem salvos no banco de dados.
Quando recebo esses dados eu preciso verificar se cada um deles está salvo no meu banco de dados `db.buscaPorId()`. Caso cada registro não esteja salvo, uma função `db.salva()` salva cada um desses novos registros no banco.
No final desse processo eu gostaria de retornar todos os dados (novos e antigos) para a minha aplicação.

O problema é na hora de dar um GET em todos os registros após o foreach, pois ele não retorna os últimos dados que acabaram de ser salvos. Somente os que já estavam salvos anteriormente...

O que tentei está no código abaixo.

Qual seria a melhor forma de resolver isso? Estou estudando promises mas ainda não consegui entender direito para colocar em prática no meu código.
Obs: o código provavelmente está cheio de falhas, então se alguém puder me dar uma dica para melhorar seria legal :)

**Função da rota**

```
sincroniza(app) {
    return function (req, res) {
        const dadosApp = req.body;

        const conexao = app.persistencia.ConexaoDb();
        const db = new app.persistencia.PontoDao(conexao);

        if(dadosApp !== ""){
            console.log('recebendo dados');
            dadosApp.forEach(dado =>{
                db.buscaPorId(dado.uuid,(erro,resultado)=>{
                    if(resultado == '' || resultado == undefined || resultado.length == 0){
                        dado.sync = 1;
                        db.salva(dado,(erro,res)=>{
                            if(erro){
                                res.send('falha ao salvar os dados')
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }

        //não retorna os últimos dados salvos
        db.lista((erro,result)=>{                
            res.json(result);
        })

}
```

**funções do bd**

```
function PontoDao(conn){
    this._conn = conn;

}

PontoDao.prototype.salva = function(ponto,callback){
    this._conn.query('INSERT INTO ponto SET ?', ponto, callback);
}

PontoDao.prototype.atualiza = function(ponto,callback) {
    this._conn.query('UPDATE ponto SET sync = ? where id = ?', [ponto.sync, ponto.id], callback);
}

PontoDao.prototype.lista = function(callback) {
    this._conn.query('SELECT * from ponto',callback);
}

PontoDao.prototype.buscaPorId = function (id,callback) {
    this._conn.query("select * from ponto where uuid = ?",[id],callback);
}

module.exports = function(){
    return PontoDao;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é um caso típico de um loop `forEach` a correr código assíncrono. Falei sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/129), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257999/129) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364465/129). Recomendo dares uma leitura para perceber melhor o problema.

No teu caso podes usar Promise.all para esperar por essas requisições e depois correr o `db.lista` dentro do `.then` do Promise.all. Repara que o Promise.all só corre depois de todos os elementos do loop `.map` neste caso terem corrido.

Para isso sugiro mudares o método listaPorId para funcionar com Promises.

Exemplo:

```js
// muda "buscaPorId" para:
PontoDao.prototype.buscaPorId = function(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    this._conn.query("select * from ponto where uuid = ?", [id], function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

PontoDao.prototype.salva = function(ponto) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    this._conn.query('INSERT INTO ponto SET ?', ponto, function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}


sincroniza(app) {
  return function(req, res) {
    const dadosApp = req.body;

    const conexao = app.persistencia.ConexaoDb();
    const db = new app.persistencia.PontoDao(conexao);

    let preSaving = [Promise.resolve()];
    if (dadosApp !== "") {
      console.log('recebendo dados');
      preSaving = dadosApp.map(dado => {
        return db.buscaPorId(dado.uuid).then(function(resultado) {
          if (!resultado || resultado.length == 0) {
            return db.salva(dado).catch(function() {
              res.send('falha ao salvar os dados')
            });
          }
        })
      });
    }
    //não retorna os últimos dados salvos
    Promise.all(preSaving).then(function() {
      db.lista((erro, result) => {
        res.json(result);
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito boa a sua resposta, @Sergio♦. Imaginei que eu poderia resolver com Promise, por isso coloquei no título. 
Agora tenho um ponto de partida para estudar melhor e terminar o meu código. Algo que estou tentando entender é o que essa linha faz exatamente?  
 let preSaving = [Promise.resolve()];

Comment: @dmgGeronimo caso o `if (dadosApp !== "") {` não for `true` então o `Promise.all` (que aceita uma array) vai consumir uma Pormise vazia e resolvida com `[Promise.resolve()];`. Faz sentido?